# Convert System::object to string array

Tags: string, c++-cli

I need to return four dimensional array of strings during the work of background worker which is receiving data via serial port.

In background worker:

```
    array<String^>^ Received = gcnew array<String^>(4);
    backgroundWorker1->ReportProgress(10,Received);
```

In report progress:

```
private: System::Void backgroundWorker1_ProgressChanged(System::Object^ sender,   System::ComponentModel::ProgressChangedEventArgs^  e)
{
    array<String^>^ Received2 = gcnew array<String^>(4);
    Received2 =(e->UserState);
}
```

I am getting:

> error C2440: '=' : cannot convert from 'System::Object ^' to 'cli::array "

which is not a surprise, but how to convert and assign `UserState` to `string array`?

Answer (score 0):

You need to cast the object handle to an array handle then check for a nullptr to see if the cast was successful e.g:

```
array<String^>^ Received2 = dynamic_cast<array<String^>^>(e->UserState);
if (Received2 != nullptr)
{
    // Cast was successful, safe to use Received2.
}
else
{
    // Cast failed, do not use Received2.
}
```